# How to increase veroboard's current capacity?

Tags: current, electrical, stripboard

I want to solder below circuit into a veroboard. As I notice my motor will draw high current. Can I paste copper tape to handle the high current?

What others modifications should I do to make circuit better? 
What value should I use for my resister?

My motor need to run for 2 hours at least. [image]

Update:I solder on the strip board without servo motor. I run with my motor. It work. But connectors become hot. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Don't run the motor power through the board at all, directly connect it to the relay.  And you probably don't want to use that 3-terminal regulator for an RC hobby servo.

Comment: @ChrisStratton For servo motor, I will connect to my Arduino 5V and GND pin. How about for the value of resistor? My initial calculation give me 74k Ohm. I am still confused by this large value.

Comment: No, do not try to power your servo from the Arduino, the current which can be drawn in stall conditions substantially exceeds the ratings.  And if you have an Arduino in this, what's the use of the verboard?  You'd do better making a wiring harness or using terminal strips for the relay.  At most you need a little chunk of it for the transistor.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I got upload my solder version 1. Is it good idea to use copper tape? For servo, I haven't do yet.

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9q5vwCESEQ) might be applicable to your problem, it's a video by Dave Jones who compares different amount of tinning. - You can easily make a tinned path on the PCB, though you will waste an insane amount of tin that way. - Why can't you do what Chris Stratton/Laptop2d suggests? So far I haven't seen any proper reasoning showing why their solutions are not okay.

Comment: Unrelated, but be prepared to add some bypass caps on that..

Comment: @HarrySvensson How to connect motor to relay directly? I still need to connect to the GND of the battery right. I will try to put tinned path.

Comment: @WesleyLee Can I know where I should put the bypass caps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either run jumper wire on top of the veroboard, or another good way would be to solder on solder braid (its made of copper) to "append" more copper onto the trace.

Something like this:

[image]

The current carrying capacity is determined by the cross sectional area of the conductor so if you can estimate the cross sectional area, you could determine the amount of current it [could carry.](https://www.wirebarn.com/Wire-Calculator-_ep_41.html)

Comment: I got use 16AWG wire and some copper tape. Will it be better?